# android doinbackground not working properly

Tags: android-asynctask

My AysynTask is not working .Please help me out

This is the log Details
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
08-08 10:54:36.939 28068-28068/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
08-08 10:54:36.941 28068-28068/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-08 10:54:36.942 28068-28068/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
08-08 10:54:36.945 28068-28094/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
08-08 10:54:36.947 28068-28094/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:31)
        at com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:20)
08-08 10:54:36.948 28068-28094/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
08-08 10:54:36.949 28068-28094/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-08 10:54:37.291 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-08 10:54:37.291 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-08 10:54:37.291 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-08 10:54:37.292 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-08 10:54:37.349 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa2d85400: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-08 10:54:37.395 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2d85400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e7eb60)
08-08 10:54:37.442 28068-28096/com.example.rajatanurag.guessthecelebrityapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa2d85400: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa0e7eb60)

Following is the code:
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        String result="";
        URL url;
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection=null;

        try
        {
            url=new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection=(HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream=urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            int data=inputStreamReader.read();

            while(data!=-1)
            {
                char current=(char)data;
                result+=current;
                data=inputStreamReader.read();
            }

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    String result = null;
    try {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            downloadTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);


        else

            result = downloadTask.execute("http://www.bollywoodhungama.com/celebrities/top-100/").get();
        Log.i("contents of url", result);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with the `AsyncTask` itself. It seems that `urls[0]` causes the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Check if you are passing the right value to your `doInBackground` method.